# TestDFSIO Benchmark - Bad Datanodes

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am attempting to run the **TestDFSIO - Write** test to benchmark my hadoop yarn cluster.

The result for 1 MB file size is as follows:

```
17/02/13 16:29:56 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: ----- TestDFSIO ----- : write
17/02/13 16:29:56 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:            Date & time: Mon Feb 13 16:29:56 IST 2017
17/02/13 16:29:56 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:        Number of files: 10
17/02/13 16:29:56 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: Total MBytes processed: 10.0
17/02/13 16:29:56 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:      Throughput mb/sec: 0.08520645524104906
17/02/13 16:29:56 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: Average IO rate mb/sec: 0.11449315398931503
17/02/13 16:29:56 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:  IO rate std deviation: 0.051399135678609
17/02/13 16:29:56 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:     Test exec time sec: 59.722
```

and for 10 MB file size, the result is

```
17/02/13 17:24:23 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: ----- TestDFSIO ----- : write
17/02/13 17:24:23 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:            Date & time: Mon Feb 13 17:24:23 IST 2017
17/02/13 17:24:23 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:        Number of files: 10
17/02/13 17:24:23 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: Total MBytes processed: 100.0
17/02/13 17:24:23 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:      Throughput mb/sec: 0.13296139598828877
17/02/13 17:24:23 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: Average IO rate mb/sec: 0.1448635458946228
17/02/13 17:24:23 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:  IO rate std deviation: 0.044048737962458215
17/02/13 17:24:23 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:     Test exec time sec: 135.863
```

**But when I try increasing the file size to 100 MB, I keep getting the following error:**

```
....
17/02/13 17:28:33 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 67% reduce 0%
17/02/13 17:28:43 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 73% reduce 0%
17/02/13 17:29:45 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 67% reduce 0%
17/02/13 17:29:46 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486983847790_0003_m_000003_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: All datanodes DatanodeInfoWithStorage[172.16.33.70:50010,DS-f6a1b4fe-66f7-4b6d-9164-f15f371471e0,DISK] are bad. Aborting...
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.setupPipelineForAppendOrRecovery(DFSOutputStream.java:1109)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.processDatanodeError(DFSOutputStream.java:871)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:401)

Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
....
```

**The MR jobs gets stuck. Is my 3 machine cluster (Centos7 OS, 4 cores & 32 GB RAM - Each) ONLY capable of writing 10 MB of file?**

Best Regards

Comment: Could be a ulimit issue, try increasing the limits on number of open files.

Comment: Hi @franklinsijo - I added the following two rows in /etc/security/limits.conf file from root user in my master machine:  * soft nofile 32768 and * soft noproc 65536. Then SCPed this file to my two slaves and then rebooted all the 3 machines. I again got the same error..but like before the MR process continued and finally, the job completed successfully with  <Test exec time sec: 646.308>. So, its close to 10 minutes for a 80 MB file along with the Bad Datanode error!

Comment: What is the hardlimit set for the files and processes? if they are lesser than the softlimit, increase it.

Comment: Hi @franklinsijo - My limits.conf file looks like foll: `* soft nofile 16384
* soft nproc  65536
* hard nofile 32768
* hard nproc  65536`. I ran the TestDFSIO with 100 MB file size. It completed Successfully, **BUT it again gave two errors** in the middle: 1) `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException....Holder does not have any open files` and once again 2) `All datanodes DatanodeInfoWithStorage[172.16.33.60:50010,DS-c4e06a70-27e2-42fe-95cf-7b04810e407d,DISK] are bad. Aborting...`

Comment: The first error could be a result of aborted speculative execution, since the job was successful it is fine. The time delay is because of the bad datanodes issue. Can you verify whether the Datanodes mentioned in the error do have sufficient space in local as well as dfs.

Comment: Hi @franklinsijo - in hdfs-site.xml, the `dfs.data.dir` is set to `file:///home/admin/volume/datanode` and the `/home` directory is mounted on `/dev/mapper/cl-home` which has **416 GB** of available space. My 2nd worker also has the same settings.

Comment: I added `<property>
<name>mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize</name>
<value>16777216</value>
</property>` in **mapred-site.xml** and `<property> 
    <name>dfs.block.size<name> 
    <value>134217728<value> 
    <description>Block size<description> 
<property>` in **hdfs-site.xml**. Well, now 100 MB is executing successfully **without** throwing the Bad Datanode error. Good sign. But when I tried 200 MB, it again gave the above two errors.

Comment: What is the hadoop version? 128MB is the default block size in hadoop2. The scenario looks like whenever the file has more than 1 block, Bad Datanode error comes up.

Comment: Hadoop 2.7.3. I have pretty much covered all the config settings. Is there some other setting for mapred/yarn that I am missing? Not sure though!